# D3 Force Layout Variable Repulsive Foces

Tags: d3.js, force-layout

I am working on a Graph which has variable sized nodes:  http://gordonsmith.github.io/Visualization/ 
(Click F2 to start the Force Layout)

Is it possible to change the repulsive forces based on node size at runtime?  Basically I would like to "encourage" the layout to not have overlapping nodes...

Comment: It doesn't look like the force layout is suitable for what you're trying to do, but [this example for collision detection](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3231298) should help. You will have to adjust the code to get correct dimensions for your elements though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The force layout allows you to pass a function to [`force.charge()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Force-Layout#charge), which would let you specify the charge strength for each node, being passed the node and its index as arguments.

If you were to create your `nodes` data in such a way that each element had an accessible property that represented its size (say the radius of a bounding circle), then you could use this data to set a relative charge value.

For example, if each element in your data had a property `r` representing its radius, you could do something like the following:

```
var force = d3.layout.force()
  .nodes(nodes)
  .size([width,height])
  .charge(function(d) {
    return -5 * d.r;
  })
  .on('tick', tick)
  .start();
```

The choice of a factor of `-5` is completely arbitrary, and you will have to choose a value that works well for your data. Positive values represent attraction, and negative values represent repulsion.

[**HERE**](http://jsbin.com/lerod/1/edit?js,output) is a simple demo of this technique in action using circles.

Comment: Perfect - and exactly where I would expect it to be!  (Above demo updated with change)

Comment: Thanks it really helped, One thing I noticed is that nodes collapsed over each other and to the center when there were links i.e      force.link(json.links), 
but when I removed this line, nodes repelled perfectly as required.
I introduced the links after the nodes were properly placed on tick() function.